# Is this how importlib.resources is supposed to be used?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is this how importlib.resources is supposed to be used?

```py
from importlib.resources import open_text
from typing import Dict

DESKTOP_AGENTS = open_text('he.data', 'user_agents.txt').readlines()


# just a function using DESKTOP_AGENTS, its functionality doesn't matter
def random_headers() -> Dict[str, str]:
    """Returns headers dict for use when making requests to web servers,
    in order to simulate a browser more realistically.
    The user agent is random."""
    return {
        'User-Agent': choice(DESKTOP_AGENTS).strip(),
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    }
```

The file with the function is `src/he/http_tools.py`.

The full package structure is here: https://github.com/Laurentiu-Andronache/he, but here's a summarized version:

```
/src/he/__init__.py
/src/he/http_tools.py
/src/he/data/__init__.py
/src/he/data/user_agents.txt
```

The library is pip-installable.

In `setup.py`, I have:

```py
    packages=find_packages(where="src"),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    package_data={'he': ['data/*.txt']},
```

Comment: Looks about right. However, after reading from the file-like object returned from invoking `open_text` you need to take care of closing it.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule: so it would be like this? 

```with open_text('he.data', 'user_agents.txt') as _:


    DESKTOP_AGENTS = _.readlines()```

Comment: @RobertCalceanu More like `with open_text('he.data', 'user_agents.txt') as f: DESKTOP_AGENTS = f.readlines()`

Comment: On a side note, I would suggest watching Barry Warsaw PyCon 2018 talk 'Get your resources faster, with importlib.resources'   https://youtu.be/ZsGFU2qh73E 
 "This talk will step through the motivations behind `importlib.resources`, the library's usage, its interfaces, and the hooks made available to third party packages."